# Apex Charts custom tooltips - how do I get category name and color?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I want to create a custom tooltip in Apex Charts. Below is what is suggested in the official docs:

```
tooltip: {
  custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
    return '<div class="arrow_box">' +
      '<span>' + series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex] + '</span>' +
      '</div>'
  }
}
```

The tooltip above will display the value only. However, I also need information about the corresponding category name (and if possible chart color):

https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/xYqyYm

[image]

I bet this info is somwhere in `w.globals` but I failed to find it there (expesially given it's a recursive object which returns `[Object Object]` when you try to copy it from the console).

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are searching for is

```
w.globals.labels[dataPointIndex]
```

For the category and maybe

```
w.globals.colors
```

Refers to the chart's colors. you can list the keys of the `globals` object with

```
Object.keys(w.globals)
```

And the correspondingg values with

```
Object.values(w.globals).map(val => val ? val.toString() : null)
```

Comment: Hey Mischa, How can I get tooltip's position from this chartContext obect ? Do you know ?

Comment: As Mischa said, for the color: `let color = w.globals.colors[seriesIndex]`

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the css file, for example:

```
     // This is for custom box
      .apexcharts-tooltip {
        border-radius: 12px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     // This is for custom header
          &.apexcharts-theme-light .apexcharts-tooltip-title {
             font-family: Lato !important;
             background-color: white;
             border-bottom: 0;
             font-weight: bold;
           }
    // This is for custom headers
      .apexcharts-tooltip-text-value {
         font-weight: normal;
         font-family: Lato;
         font-size: 12px;
      }
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to change the options in the JS file if only to change the tooltips styles, just change the css file. But, if you want to change the format value, you can use the formatter on tooltips. for more details can be read at this link: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
::ng-deep .apexcharts-tooltip{
 background-color:#52575C !important;
 color:#FEFEFE;
 border-color:#FEFEFE;
}

::ng-deep .apexcharts-tooltip-title{
 background-color:#52575C !important;
 color:#FEFEFE;
 border-color:#FEFEFE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).