# How to display the Apex Charts datapoint's datetime value in tooltip?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm having trouble getting the datapoint's corresponding x-axis value which is `datetime`, to display in the tooltip of the datapoint. Specifically, where within the `w.globals` object.

```
var chartOptions = {
...
xaxis: { type: "datetime" },
tooltip: {
    x: { format: "dd MMM yyyy" },
    y: {
        formatter: (value, { series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w })=> {
            return '<div>'+'Value: ' + value + '</div>' +
                   '<div>'+'Timestamp: ' + ?? + '</div>'
    }
 }
...
}
```

I'm following along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565189/6519224), unsuccessful so far. Seems it works only on the categorical data as demonstrated [here](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/NBdyvV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `w.globals.seriesX` array contains the X values for DateTime series.

```js
const timestamp = w.globals.seriesX[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. May I know what does `w` stands for, and its fields definitions?

Comment: would you mind posting the completed 'after' code, with the successful solution you implemented?